# MYSQL order limit with PHP variable

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code below

```
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id LIMIT 10");

    while($f = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $match = 0; //In reality it's an array search function which returns 1 on match

    if($match == 1) {
    echo"Show content!";
    }

    }
```

Im trying to make an list with 10 rows, and i have a function which uses "name" from table to run an search query with an array generated by twitter API. In example if i get 3 matching records, i still want to show a list with 10 rows but hide the matching elements from there.

At the moment the script hides the matching elements and shows 7 rows instead of 10.

That is what i need help with, cheers :)

Comment: Add your search criteria into sql query

Comment: cant able to understand ,please write clearly

Comment: @AndreyMischenko can't add criteria to sql query, since the array is stdClassobject and it's fetched from twitter api.

Comment: @KarthickKumarGanesh which part didn't you understand?

Comment: I don't understand anything what you're trying to do ?

Comment: @user1936204 Store the unmatched elements separately?

Comment: Im trying to make an list with 10 rows, and i have a function which uses "name" from table to run an search query with an array generated by twitter API. In example if i get 3 matching records, i still want to show a list with 10 rows but hide the matching elements from there.

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Process the data you are getting from the twitter api, collect the data you need in an array and query the database afterwards.
Something like that:

```
<?php
    $collectArray = array();

    foreach ($twitterData as $index => $data) {
        if ($someCriteria === TRUE) {
            $collectArray[] = $data;
        }
    }

    $implodedCollectArray = "'" . implode("', '", $collectArray) . "'";

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `some_column` IN (" . $implodedCollectArray . ")";
    $query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    while($f = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        echo $f['column'];
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, i will try this out when i get home.

Comment: @user1936204 No problemo, glad I could help ;)

Answer (score 0):

reinitilize match variable as the code:

```
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id LIMIT 10");
  while($f = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
  if($f['name']!='variable_name_twiter'){
     $match = 1; //In reality it's an array search function which returns 1 on match
  }

  if($match == 1) {
    echo"Show content!";
  }
  $match = 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes but, how to make the query fetch 3 more rows if search functions matches 3 rows.

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Im trying to make an list with 10 rows, and i have a function which uses "name" from table to run an search query with an array generated by twitter API. In example if i get 3 matching records, i still want to show a list with 10 rows but hide the matching elements from there.

At the moment the script hides the matching elements and shows 7 rows instead of 10.

Comment: It won't still work out, imagine if 1 row matches the twitter variable. It will be hidden and 9 rows will be shown. But i want that 10 rows will be shown and 1 will be hidden.